# Taylor polynomial of 2nd degree

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Need to find the Taylor polynomial P2(x) of 2nd degree at 0 of the following function:
>   $$
> f(x)= \frac12 \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right), \quad x \in (-1,1)
> $$

What i've done so far:
$$
1/2(ln((1+x)/(1-x)) = 1/2(ln(1+x)-ln(1-x))
$$
taylor series first we need the f(0) which in this case is 0 as ln(1)=0

And because the function is odd, we don't need to derivative two times (I think). 
Literally stuck here, don't know what to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can simplify to write
$$
f(x) = \frac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)}{2}
$$
and therefore compute
$$
f'(x) = \frac12 \left[\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right]
      = \frac{(1+x)^{-1} + (1-x)^{-1}}{2}
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \frac{-(1+x)^{-2} + (1-x)^{-2}}{2}
$$
Therefore, $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1$ and $f''(0) = 0$.

Taylor's formula says that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(x)\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!},
$$
and applying this for $a=0$ and $n \le 2$ we get
$$
f(x) \approx f(0) + xf'(0) + f''(0) \frac{x^2}{2} = x.
$$